# How does this usage of the composition operator work without a second argument?

Tags: haskell, function-composition

I came across a usage of the . operator that I don't quite understand.

I tried to reason about it myself, but the conclusion I reach is different from what GHCI produces.

I'm using `:t` to inspect the type of the expression.

The functions I'm using are the `last` and `(.)`, which have the following signatures:

```hs
last :: [a] -> a
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

The function I am confused about is this:

```hs
(last .)
```

I am not sure what this construct is, but I assumed that it would be similar to function composition.
Using my reasoning, I would expect this to produce the following function:

```hs
(last .) :: (b -> [c]) -> (a -> b) -> a -> [c]
```

What `:t` actually gives me is this:

```hs
(last .) :: (a -> [c]) -> a -> c
```

Comment: With an operator `(x &)`, this is equivalent to `(&) x`, so you wrote `(.) last`, so it expects a function `f` as second parameter, and then creates a function `last . f`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an example of [*infix operator sectioning* [Haskell-wiki]](https://wiki.haskell.org/Section_of_an_infix_operator):

> (...)
>
> `(2^)` (left section) is equivalent to `(^) 2`, or more verbosely `\x -> 2 ^ x`.

So we here constructed a function that looks like:

```
\f -> last . f
```

or shorter:

```
(.) last
```

The [**`(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:.) function takes two functions `g` and `h`, and creates a function `\x -> g (h x)`. Here `g` is thus `last`.

We thus created a function that takes as input a function `f :: b -> [c]`, that then returns `last . f`.